# Hash from object's content as object ID: fast alternatives for SHA256

Tags: hash, blob, identity, sha256

I'm working on design of [Content-addressable storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_storage), so I'm looking for a hash function to generate object identifiers. Every object should get short ID based on its content in that way: `object_id = hash(object_content)`.

Prerequisites:

1. Hash-function should be fast.
2. Collision probability must be as low as possible.
3. Optimal ID length is `32` bytes in order to address `256^32` objects at max (but this requirement may be relaxed).

Taking into account these requirements, I picked up `SHA256` hash, but unfortunately it's not fast enough for my purposes. The fastest implementations of `SHA256` that I was able to benchmark were `openssl` and `boringssl`: on my desktop `Intel Core I5 6400` it gave about `420 MB/s` per core. Other implementations (like `crypto/rsa` in Go) are even slower. I would like to replace `SHA256` with other hash function that provides the same collision guarantees as `SHA256`, but gives betters throughput (at least `600 MB/s` per core).

Please share your opinion about possible options to solve this problem.

Also I would like to note that hardware update (like purchasing modern CPU with `AVX512` instruction set) is not possible. The main point is to find hash function that will provide better performance on commodity hardware.

Comment: check out hashes here: https://github.com/rurban/smhasher. Btw, I don't really know what you mean by "address", but a 32-byte ID can have 256^32 different values (not 8^32).

Comment: @geza, thanks, that was a mistake. By "address" I mean the upper limit for the total amount of objects that may exist in a system.

Comment: 1. A 256^32 upper limit for the total amount of objects that may exist in a system is really big, about 10^76! Consider that there are only about 10^78 to 10^82 atoms in the known, observable universe I wonder how you will store these objects. 2. SHA256 is not collision free.

Comment: 3. When hashing for indexing one generally used a fast hash and expects collisions, the collisions are felt with by using lists or re-hashing. 4. If *'if two objects with different content got same ID, the identity system would be totally broken'* the system is broken by design when using just a hash.

Comment: @zaph

1. I agree that this amount of keys is too big and not likely to be ever reached. But mature key-value storages for a some reasons tend to use long keys. For example, https://github.com/reverbrain/elliptics uses SHA512 as internal storage key;
2. Yes, SHA256 is not collision free, but the probability to get collisions is close to zero. SHA256 is a default hash for ZFS built-in deduplication system, and, as far as I know, the don't have any collision checking techniques when SHA256 is enabled (they check for collisions only when using weak hashes like Fletcher4).

Comment: @zaph
3. Could you please share a little bit more information about "lists and re-hashing", I've never heard this before;
4. I can't see any alternatives for using anything but cryptographic hash. Consider situation when I asked for an object by ID and identity system returned me list of different objects. How should I choose the right one? Taking into account that size of objects may be relatively big, up to several megabytes.

Comment: 5. See [Basics of Hash Tables](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/tutorial/). 6. Back before book learning was out-dated in favor of google searches we used to read Don Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming. 7. This is probably an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info) where more information on what you are trying to accomplish would held to get a better answer. 8. SHA-512 is used a lot these days because it can be faster than SHA-256 on 64-bit hardware—so why not.

Comment: Here is a real-world hashing usage. A bottle club will store a member's bottle (booze) in bins labeled by the members last two membership numbers. Consider 500 members, 100 bins and several bottlers per member. When a member wants a bottle he supplies the last two digits of his membership number. The bar keeper goes to that bin and then searches for that members bottle, that is resolving the collision. That is an example of one type of hash table collision handling. **If you allow collisions only a portion of the data need be fast hashed and only occasionally a larger hash or full compare.**

Comment: Realistically, how many objects and what is the size range? It is probably not a faster hash but a better algorithm that you need.

Comment: "I can't see any alternatives for using anything but cryptographic hash." Why? There is absolutely no need to use a cryopto hash, if your intent is only to map [data] -> [some small ID]. The only reason I'd use a crypto hash for this purpose is that it is proven to be good. But there are non-crypto hashes as well, which are good too (in the sense they don't generate collisions). It just doesn't make any sense to pay the price that SHA256 at best ten times slower than a modern non-crypto hash.

Comment: @zaph full comparison is not possible at all. The case is the KV-store for blobs with deduplication support. Every document is splitted to segments. Every segment is stored across the cluster nodes. In order to compose document and return it to the client you need to fetch segments from the cluster nodes. Mapping `segmentID` <-> `nodeID` is stored in the index. You have to use hash from segment content as `segmentID`, otherwise segment deduplication is not possible. There will be about 10^10 of segments with the size range from several bytes to several megabytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Cityhash](https://github.com/google/cityhash) and [HighwayHash](https://github.com/google/highwayhash). Both have 256-bit variants, and much faster than SHA256. Cityhash is faster, but it is a non-cryptographic hash. HighwayHash is slower (but still faster than SHA256), and a [secure](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.06257.pdf) hash.

All modern non-cryptographic hashes are **much** faster than SHA256. If you're willing to use a 128-bit hash, you'll have more [options](https://github.com/rurban/smhasher).

Note, that you may want to consider using a 128-bit hash, as it may be adequate for your purpose. For example, if you have 10<sup>10</sup> different objects, the probability that you have a collision with a quality 128-bit hash is less than 10<sup>-18</sup>. Check out the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).

Comment: thank you, just let me make sure that I understood it correctly... Is it possible to compare hash functions by the probability of collisions? If so, do you mean that there are non-cryptographical hashes (that you've mentioned above) which provide the same collision resistance as SHA256?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: Good non-crypto hashes *should* have the same collision resistance as crypto hashes. Of course, there is no guarantee. That's why the SMHasher test exists, to check out the behavior of hashes. If a hash passes it, it should not be a bad hash, it doesn't have a major flaw. But, if you want to be absolutely sure that you get the best possible hash, use a well known crypto hash. Some of the hashes in SMHasher designed by google, and google actively uses them. So I think these hashes must be good.

Comment: OK, I'm going to try HighwayHash. Thanks again :)

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: if you want to decrease the possibility of collision, use two or even more hashes :) This still much faster than SHA256, and has much lower collision probability (if the concatenated bit-length is larger than 256).

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: btw, SHA256 has support on current x86 CPUs, you may want to utilize it, if possible. This way SHA256 becomes much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, for my use-case `BLAKE2S_256` turns out to be a better option than `SHA256`.